# python - beautiful soup link parsing not working

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm new to beautiful soup trying to get it to work for a thing i'm trying to do.  Having a basic issue.  I'm trying to output the html so that i can parse it.  I want to display it for amazon which i get a partial display.  However, the other urls I get all the html displayed.

**Question**

How do I download the entire amazon page html?

**Code**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get("https://www.amazon.com/Python-Crash-Course-2nd-Edition/dp/1593279280/")
#page = requests.get("https://dataquestio.github.io/web-scraping-pages/ids_and_classes.html")
#page = requests.get("https://www.monster.com/jobs/search/?q=Software-Developer&where=Australia")


soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
print (soup)

print (soup.title)
```

**Desired results**

display all page html for the amazon URL

**Actual**

```
<!--
        To discuss automated access to Amazon data please contact api-services-support@amazon.com.
        For information about migrating to our APIs refer to our Marketplace APIs at https://developer.amazonservices.com/ref=rm_5_sv, or our Product Advertising API at https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/gp/advertising/api/detail/main.html/ref=rm_5_ac for advertising use cases.
-->
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<meta content="ie=edge" http-equiv="x-ua-compatible"/>
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" name="viewport"/>
<title>Sorry! Something went wrong!</title>
<style>
  html, body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0
  }

  img {
    border: 0
  }

  #a {
    background: #232f3e;
    padding: 11px 11px 11px 192px
  }

  #b {
    position: absolute;
    left: 22px;
    top: 12px
  }

  #c {
    position: relative;
    max-width: 800px;
    padding: 0 40px 0 0
  }

  #e, #f {
    height: 35px;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 1em
  }

  #e {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 10px;
    border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px
  }

  #f {
    cursor: pointer;
    background: #febd69;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    padding: 0 12px
  }

  @media (max-width: 500px) {
    #a {
      padding: 55px 10px 10px
    }

    #b {
      left: 6px
    }
  }

  #g {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 30px 0
  }

  #g img {
    max-width: 90%
  }

  #d {
    display: none
  }

  #d[src] {
    display: inline
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<a href="/ref=cs_503_logo"><img alt="Amazon.com" id="b" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/error/logo._TTD_.png"/></a>
<form accept-charset="utf-8" action="/s" id="a" method="GET" role="search">
<div id="c">
<input id="e" name="field-keywords" placeholder="Search"/>
<input name="ref" type="hidden" value="cs_503_search"/>
<input id="f" type="submit" value="Go"/>
</div>
</form>
<div id="g">
<div><a href="/ref=cs_503_link"><img alt="Sorry! Something went wrong on our end. Please go back and try again or go to Amazon's home page." src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/error/500_503.png"/></a>
</div>
<a href="/dogsofamazon/ref=cs_503_d" rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank"><img alt="Dogs of Amazon" id="d"/></a>
<script>document.getElementById("d").src = "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/error/" + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 43) + 1) + "._TTD_.jpg";</script>
</div>
</body>
</html>

<title>Sorry! Something went wrong!</title>
```

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be intentional. Amazon blocks access for robots. As you can see from the first line of the result `To discuss automated access to Amazon data please contact api-services-support@amazon.com.` they want you to use [API](https://developer.amazonservices.com/) access to allow you to scrape amazon pages.

Comment: Yeah figured since like you shared it states in the html.  The question is how do you get around it? Since clearly you can load the html up in a browser and if you want your can save it as a source and then parse the saved file.

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide your headers. So for example:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {"User-Agent": "# Search My User Agent And Paste It Here For Example: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.102 Safari/537.36"}

page = requests.get("https://www.amazon.com/Python-Crash-Course-2nd-Edition/dp/1593279280/", headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser') # Also change this page.text not page.content

print(soup.title)
```

Comment: Hmm looks this works but when I run it.  i get <title dir="ltr">Robot Check</title>